# How to config nginx to tail log on web browser

Tags: nginx, tail

My goal is to see the newest log messages on web page.

I know I could use `tail -f <file>` to trace the latest 10 line log messages on terminal.

But today, I want to config nginx, so that I could see the same result on web.

---

For example, when I access to http://192.168.1.200/nginx (My Nginx Host)

I could see the files under `/var/log/nginx`

```
Index of /nginx/
-------------------------------------------------
../
access.log           08-Aug-2019 16:43        20651
error.log            08-Aug-2019 16:43        17810
```

And when I access to http://192.168.1.200/nginx/access.log

I could see the same result as `tail -f /var/log/nginx/access.log` in terminal (and it is dynamic).

/etc/nginx/conf.d/log.conf

```
server {
    listen       80;
    root    /var/log/nginx;

    location /nginx {
        root    /var/log/;
        default_type    text/plain;
        autoindex   on;
    }
}
```

This is my config, but there are 2 points that doesn't meet my requirements:

1. I want to access to log page by accessing `/log/access.log` not by `/nginx/access.log`
2. When I access to `/log/access.log`, this page is static.

Comment: Were you able to find out how to do it? Could you share a solution here?

Comment: Not yet. I think I should use some package and something like websocket to do that.